# Sections in Infopath

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

How do I insert a space between sections in InfoPath? I've tried searching the web, but all I can find is how to delete extra spaces between sections.  I want to add a space between two sections so I can add another section between them.
I used to know this but I've forgotten.  I remember it's only a couple of keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Make some space by hitting enter at the end of form and then drag and drop Section.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IymCx.png)